# Can regex do a replace with some of the found content?

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a plugin for a CMS (Joomla) to extract part numbers from the Joomla Articles and build a string of static HTML wrapped around it with the exact part number in it.

The entire article is stored in $article->text.

These are the steps:

1. Find {myplugin}ABCDEF1234,"Flux Capacitor"{/myplugin}
2. Extract the part number (For example: ABCDEF1234)
3. Build the replacement HTML with the unique part number in it
   entirely replacing {myplugin}ABCDEF1234,"Flux Capacitor"{/myplugin}.

Note: In this example, we would be ignoring the category field of "Flux Capacitor" since only the part number needs to be extracted to build the static HTML replacement. The category field would be used by another program for reporting.

The static HTML would look something like this:

```
<iframe style="width:120px;height:240px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//thebigpartserver.com/stuff/q?partno=**PARTNO**&link_opens_in_new_window=true&price_color=333333&title_color=0066c0&bg_color=ffffff">
    </iframe>
```

and I need to replace this:

```
{myplugin}ABCDEF1234,"Flux Capacitor"{/myplugin}
```

with that:

```
<iframe style="width:120px;height:240px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//thebigpartserver.com/stuff/q?partno=ABCDEF1234&link_opens_in_new_window=true&price_color=333333&title_color=0066c0&bg_color=ffffff">
    </iframe>
```

Can this be done with a regex? Or is this making the regex to complicated?

If it is parsed and then using conditional logic outside the regex, wouldn't I need to save a pointer of where {myplugin}...{/myplugin} occurs since $article->text is a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that's what you use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for:

```
$re = '/\{myplugin\}(\w+),[^{}]+\{\/myplugin\}/';
$str = '{myplugin}ABCDEF1234,"Flux Capacitor"{/myplugin}';
$subst = '<iframe style="width:120px;height:240px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="//thebigpartserver.com/stuff/q?partno=\\1&link_opens_in_new_window=true&price_color=333333&title_color=0066c0&bg_color=ffffff">    </iframe>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mfBhyg/1).

Note: I'm assuming that part numbers consist of alphanumeric characters and are followed by a comma.

Comment: And this would still work if there were several of these in the same Joomla article's $article->text? Such as: {myplugin}ABCDEF1234,"Flux Capacitor"{/myplugin} {myplugin}ABCDEF5678,"Hair Curler"{/myplugin} ?

Comment: @EdwardCoast `preg_replace` replaces all the matches of the regular expression in the same way.

Comment: @EdwardCoast: Yes, this will work with any number matches per string. No need to save a pointer of where the matches are - that's the regex engine's job. One thing you need to be aware of is that this regex can't handle nested `{myplugin}` tags, i. e. no `{}`s may occur within such a tag.